Plotly interactive widgets: show plot with default values upon running cell
I've got an interactive plotly plot with 5 dropdowns in my jupyter notebook, 2 of which are dependent on one of them. Everything works fine once I update any of the dropdowns. However, whenever I first run the cell, the dropwdowns and the markdown text shows up but there are 2 white empty spaces where the heatmaps are displayed once I start updating any of the dropdowns. I have defined default values for the dropdowns, but how can I get the plots to show up using those values whenever I first run the cell, so there are no empty spaces?
Left and right version options of the dropdown depend on whatever question ID is selected.
# Set default for questions and versions
default_question_id = df['question_id'].iloc[0]
default_question_versions = df[df['question_id'] == default_question_id]['question_version'].unique()

# Dropdowns
question_id_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=df['question_id'].unique(),
    description='Question ID:',
    value=default_question_id,
    style={'description_width': 'initial', 'width': 'auto'},  
)

last_n_runs_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[5, 10, 15, 20],  
    description='Last N Runs:',
    value=10,  
    style={'description_width': 'initial', 'width': 'auto'},  
)

left_version_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Left Version:',
    options=default_question_versions,
    value=default_question_versions[0],  
    style={'description_width': 'initial', 'width': 'auto'},  
)

right_version_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Right Version:',
    options=default_question_versions,
    value=default_question_versions[0], 
    style={'description_width': 'initial', 'width': 'auto'},  
)

model_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=["1", "2"],  
    description='Model:',
    value="1",  # set default value
    style={'description_width': 'initial', 'width': 'auto'},  
)

# Function to update version dropdown options
def update_version_options(change):
    selected_question_id = change.new
    if selected_question_id is not None:
        versions = df[df['question_id'] == selected_question_id]['question_version'].unique()
        left_version_dropdown.options = versions
        right_version_dropdown.options = versions

# Update the options for version dropdowns upon changes to question_id
question_id_dropdown.observe(update_version_options, names='value')


# Function to create heatmap
def create_heatmap(question_id, last_n_runs, version, model):
    q_archive_df['question_version'] = q_archive_df['question_version'].astype(float)
    question_body = q_archive_df[(q_archive_df['question_id'] == question_id) & (q_archive_df['question_version'] == version)]['question'].values

    if len(question_body) == 0:
        question_body = f"No question found for version {version}"
    else:
        question_body = question_body[0]

    display(Markdown(f"**Version {version}:**\n\n{question_body}"))
    
    # Data for specified question_id and models
    filtered_data = df[(df['question_id'] == question_id) & (df['model'] == model) & (df['question_version'] == version)]

    # Get number of unique runs
    unique_runs = filtered_data['run_id'].nunique()

    # Adjust last_n_runs if it's greater than the available data
    last_n_runs = min(last_n_runs, unique_runs)
    
    filtered_data.reset_index(inplace=True)

    # Group by 'run_id', 'model', and 'task'
    filtered_data_grouped = filtered_data.groupby(['run_id', 'model', 'task'])
    
    filtered_data = filtered_data.drop_duplicates(subset=['run_id', 'task'], keep='first')
    
    # Create pivot tables using the grouped DataFrames
    pivot_accuracy = filtered_data.pivot(index='run_id', columns='task', values='accuracy').astype(float)

    pivot_accuracy = pivot_accuracy.iloc[::-1] # Hotfix 
       
    # Annotated heatmap
    heatmap = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
        z=pivot_accuracy.values[:last_n_runs].astype(int),
        x=list(pivot_accuracy.columns),
        y=list(pivot_accuracy.index[:last_n_runs]),
        colorscale=heatmap_colors,
        hoverongaps=False,
        hoverinfo='text',  # Add hover text and z value
        text=[[f"Accuracy: {val}" for val in row] for row in pivot_accuracy.values[:last_n_runs]],
        showscale=False,
        zmin=0,  
        zmax=1   
    )
    
    heatmap.update_layout(
        title=f"Accuracy by Task for Question {question_id} - {version}",
        xaxis_title="Task",
        yaxis_title="Run ID",
        margin=title_margin_value

    )

    display(heatmap)


def update_heatmaps(left_version, right_version, question_id, last_n_runs, model):
    create_heatmap(question_id, last_n_runs, left_version, model)
    create_heatmap(question_id, last_n_runs, right_version, model)

widgets.interactive(
    update_heatmaps,
    question_id=question_id_dropdown,
    last_n_runs=last_n_runs_dropdown,
    left_version=left_version_dropdown,
    right_version=right_version_dropdown,
    model=model_dropdown
)


